# How can I send a gRPC message whose format is determined at runtime?

Tags: java, grpc

I'm primarily interested in doing this in Java, but seeing a solution in any language would be helpful.

According to various documentation that I'm reading the default workflow with gRPC is

- Write a `.proto` file
- Generate client and/or server code from that file
- Write your program and compile it together with the generated code

What I want to do is programmaticaly read in a message schema (either from a `.proto` file or through some other means), and then send some data that's laid out according to that schema to some address.

The only way I can see to do that right now is to shell out, generate code in a temp directory, invoke the compiler, load the compiled code, and use reflection to get at the intended functions.

That sounds like an extreme hack to me. Is there a simpler option available?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you're using proto definitions, then the format is always Protobuf, not determined at runtime

Comment: how do you plan to populate object with unknown schema?

Comment: It is known - just not at the moment the program is compiled. Essentially I'm trying to write a tool to ping different services. I can't generate the code when the tool is compiled because at that point I don't know with what services I'll interact.

Comment: We have a similar use case: a testing tool that currently does REST calls based on an input test configuration, and should be able to do the same with gRPC calls. Speed is unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

In gRPC Java, the generated code and the protos are optional, and you don't actually need them (though they are convenient).   To dynamically interpret the message you will need to define your own [Marshaller](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.15.x/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/MethodDescriptor.java#L142), which works with an `InputStream` to access the raw message bytes.  From here you can buffer them into an array, and decide how to parse them.

As a similar exercise, I wrote a more in depth tutorial on using [JSON with gRPC](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json).   The principle should be the same for your code.