# How to implement gRPC Gateway in a node backend

Tags: grpc, grpc-node, grpc-gateway

I'm trying to implement [gRPC gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) in a Node.JS server following the [installation](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#installation) guide.

The steps are writen for `golang` but I tried to do in Node.JS.

I found [this](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/1525) response, and also some packages like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-dynamic-gateway) so is possible implement in node.

After read "insatallation guide", the main problem seems to be get the binary files:

- protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
- protoc-gen-openapiv2
- protoc-gen-go
- protoc-gen-go-grpc

I have downloaded first two binaries from [here](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/releases) so the problem maybe are last two.

I assume `go` is from `golang` so I have to search something like `protoc-gen-node-grpc`. And I've seen [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protoc-gen-grpc) npm package, but, I want to implement by myself as much as is possible. I don't want to depends from third-party people.

At this point I have first to binaries into my path but no the last two.

Once defined gRPC service, next step is generate gRPC stubs. I have this line:

```sh
RUN protoc -I=. mygrpc.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./my/folder/ --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:./my/folder/
```

And this generate the files ok. I don't know if I have to use `--js_out` and `--grpc-web_out` to create client and service files.

Then, next step is to generate reverse-proxy using `protoc-gen-grpc-gateway`.

I do (as guide says):

```sh
protoc -I=./my/path/ myproto.proto \
  --grpc-gateway_out ./my/path/ \
    --grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
    --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
    --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true
```

And this generate a `.go` file: `myproto.pb.gw.go`.

Into the file says:

```golang
// Code generated by protoc-gen-grpc-gateway. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: myproto.proto

/*
Package myproto is a reverse proxy.

It translates gRPC into RESTful JSON APIs.
*/
```

So I assume steps are correctly done but: How can I execute this into my Node.JS server?

I have a node project using a Express API, I want to use grpc-gateway instead of express API endpoint... but I only have a `.go` file.

My proto version is:

> libprotoc 3.14.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the issue comment, grpc-gateway only generate Go code. Feel free to use Go, there only need generate code from proto and add service. You can reference my sample code in Java [helloworlde/grpc-gateway](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-gateway); And buf is better than protoc to generate code. If you want write all by yourself, you can reference [ReflectionCall.java](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample/blob/main/reflection/src/main/java/io/github/helloworlde/grpc/ReflectionCall.java) wirte in Java, it can call server without generate code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and examples. Chinese language doesn't help so much but I will take a look the next days. Thanks again!

Comment: You can reference this question also, and it is easy to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133529/how-to-create-grpc-client-directly-from-protobuf-without-compiling-it-into-java/65641262#65641262