# How to create GRPC server directly from protobuf without compiling it into java code

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, proto

It is necessary to implement a universal GRPC server as a stub.

Didn't find anything similar for the server, only for the client.

Thank you very much!

Comment: the IDL does not contain any logic, how will you create a server without any service implementation?

Comment: What is it supposed to to? Simply accept the data?

Comment: I would like to get a mechanism that would allow creating a server without implementation, which could receive and send the data described in the proto diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to process the protobuf messages, then you need to create a [`Marshaller`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/MethodDescriptor.Marshaller.html) that serializes to/from `byte[]`, a `MethodDescriptor` for each method you want to support, and a [`ServerCallHandler`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerCallHandler.html) for your application logic. You might find a [grpc proxy mockup](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/compare/308a7c7...grpc-proxy) helpful. Those can be combined together to pass to [`serverBuilder.addService(ServerServiceDefinition)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#addService-io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition-). You can also use [`ServerCalls`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/ServerCalls.html#asyncUnaryCall-io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.UnaryMethod-) to help make a `ServerCallHandler`.

```java
class ByteMarshaller implements MethodDescriptor.Marshaller<byte[]> {
  @Override public byte[] parse(InputStream stream) {
    try {
      return ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

  @Override public InputStream stream(byte[] value) {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(value);
  }
};
class YourHandler extends ServerCallHandler<byte[],byte[]> {...}

MethodDescriptor<> desc = MethodDescriptor.<byte[], byte[]>newBuilder()
    // UNKNOWN is fine, but specify the type if you know it
    .setType(MethodDescriptor.MethodType.UNKNOWN)
    .setFullMethodName("package.YourService/Method"))
    .setRequestMarshaller(new ByteMarshaller())
    .setResponseMarshaller(new ByteMarshaller())
    .build();
serverBuilder.addService(
    ServiceDescriptor.newBuilder("package.YourService")
      .addMethod(ServerMethodDefinition.create(desc, new YourHandler()))
      .build());
```

If you want to parse the protobuf, then you can use `DynamicMessage` with gRPC's Protobuf Marshaller. [A similar client-side question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61144510/4690866) explains that process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to use the generated server for testing purposes? If so, there is a practice called [service virtualization or API simulation - a subset of the test double family](https://www.infoq.com/articles/stubbing-mocking-service-virtualization-differences/). It allows you to "simulate" or "stub" the real system for the purpose of testing your system under test. Some of those tools allow importing schema files to generate stubs (i.e. Swagger/OpenAPI/Proto/WSDL/...).

[Wikipedia contains a list of those tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools). Looking at that list today one of those tools that support gRPC is called [Traffic Parrot which allows you to create gRPC mocks based on your Proto files](https://trafficparrot.com/documentation/5.26.x/grpc.html#edit-grpc-skeletons). There are also open-source tools like [GripMock](https://github.com/tokopedia/gripmock) but it does not generate stubs based on Proto files, you have to create them manually.

Keep in mind, the stub/mock/simulator generated will be only a [test double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double), it will not replicate the full behavior of the system the Proto file corresponds to. The tool that imports the Proto file and generates a server test double can only know the syntax of the messages, not semantics nor the behaviour of the real system.

If you wanted to also replicate partially the semantics of the messages consider a [recording of gRPC messages to create service stubs](https://trafficparrot.com/documentation/5.26.x/grpc.html#recording-grpc), that way you can see the sample data as well.