# gRPC create stub from reflection server (not dynamic messages)

Tags: reflection, compilation, grpc

If I have a grpc server running that is exposing the reflection service, is there some way to connect to it and generate the stub in some language to call it?

Like using `protoc` but referencing the server instead of the `.proto` files

I don't want a way to dynamically call the message, but rather a way to generate the proper Java (or other languages) stub code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done by create a generic stub and then generate descriptor, you can reference [How to create GRPC client directly from protobuf without compiling it into java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133529/how-to-create-grpc-client-directly-from-protobuf-without-compiling-it-into-java/65641262#65641262) in Java

Comment: Maybe I wrongly stated the issue, I don't want to use the dynamic message, but rather compile it into Java code